# How to create a CIVector from array of CGFloat?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cifilter, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to create the CICrossPolynomial filter type in Swift.

I am unsure how to create the syntax to do it however.

The documentation specifies a CIVector which has an array of floats?

```
A CIVector object whose display name is RedCoefficients.

Default value: [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] Identity: [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

But how do I actually declare such a CIVector? There is one constructor that has this signature

```
CIVector(values: <UnsafePointer<CGFloat>>, count: <UInt>)
```

But when I try

```
var floatArr:Array<CGFloat> = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var vector = CIVector(values: floatArr, count: floatArr.count)
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list type (values: @lvaue Array<CGFloat>, count:Int)
```

Do you know how I can properly create a CIVector with an array of CGFloats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`floatArr.count` has the type `Int`, but the `count:` parameter has the type `UInt`,
therefore you need to convert it explicitly:

```
let floatArr: [CGFloat] = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var vector = CIVector(values: floatArr, count: UInt(floatArr.count))
```